# What is the different between traefik.domain and traefik.frontend.rule=Host

Tags: traefik

`traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com` redirect requests to example.com to that backend. Then what is the usage of `traefik.domain`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default frontend rule is Host:{containerName}.{domain} or Host:{service}.{project_name}.{domain}

Assuming you are using Docker as a provider, setting traefik.frontend.rule=foobar.example.com is equivalent to setting traefik.domain=exemple.com with a container called foobar

This is documented [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/)

Comment: Is there any documentation of the default frontend rule?

Comment: Added link to the documentation

Comment: I  thought the documentation was on `traefik.domain` row. I can find it now.